# Designing Font in The Middle of Lines Using CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to design a font in the middle of two separated lines, but I can't find the solution. You can see in picture, that there's a word "in" with `text-align: center;` and placed in the middle of two lines. Do anyone know how to make that happen?

[image: jpg file for the homefront webpage]

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: Sorry, but thank you very much. I searched before, but it seems the keyword i used didn't quite right.